# Cast the type dynamically in multiple inheritance scenario

Tags: c++

Assume there is a template class that is an abstract interface to keep track a series of data.

```
template<typename T>
class SeriesData
{
    virtual T valueAt(int i) const = 0;
};
```

I decide to use vector to store the data so I inherits from it, I also add a function to add value to series.

```
template<typename T> class MySeriesData : public SeriesData<T>
{
    T valueAt(int i) const {return values_[i];}
    void add(const T& value) {values_.push_back(value);}
private:
    std::vector<T> values_;
};
```

The class that is going to use the series of data.

```
template<typename T>
class AT
{
public:
    T data() const {return data_;}
    void setData(SeriesData<T>* data) {delete data_; data_ = data;}

private:
    SeriesData<T> *data_;
};

class IT : public AT<int>
{
};

class ST : public AT<string>
{
};
```

There is also a class that implements some common logic:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){}
    virtual ~A() {}
protected:
    void common() {cout << "A common" << endl;}
};
```

And there are two classes, each of which inherits from `IT` and `ST`, and both of which need to inherit from `A`. I want to have them inherit from A because there are so much common logic.

```
class Numbers : public A , public IT
{
};

class Strings : public A , public ST
{
};
```

In the main logic, I will use a pointer in type of A to dynamically create the instance of either Numbers or Strings based on the type client wants.

```
A* item;
if(type == NUMBER)
    item = new Numbers();
else if(type == STRING)
    item = new Strings();
```

I can just use item to do those common things, which is good.

```
item->common();
```

However, for those logic that are related to AT. I would need to check the real type and then do cast.

```
item->common();    
if(type == NUMBER)
{
    IT* itemNumber = static_cast<Numbers*>(item);
    itemNumber->setData(new MySeries<int>());  
}
else if(type == STRING)
{
    ST* itemString = static_cast<Strings*>(item);
    itemString->setData(new MySeries<string>());  
}

.....
if(type == NUMBER)
{
    //Have to cast from A to the a type of AT first
    Numbers* itemNumber = static_cast<Numbers*>(item);
    //Another conversion
    MySeries<int>* numberValues = (MySeries<int>*)itemNumber->data();
    numberValues->add(1); 
}
else if(type == STRING)
{
    Strings* itemString = static_cast<Strings*>(item);
    MySeries<string>* stringValues = (MySeries<string>*)itemString->data();
    stringValues->add("1");   
}
```

This is annoying when the code is full of these `if...else` or `switch...case`, especially when there are more and more types.

Is it possible to cast the type more smartly? It will be nice if I can always (or in most of cases) use pointer of A to do all the stuffs.

Comment: If you have to downcast, there's a large possibility there's a better "more OOP" way of doing things. At the very least, you're breaking [the Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: If you, for some reason, cannot create a common interface type, there is always the possibility of using type erasure.

Comment: Note that `item = static_cast<B*>(item)` doesn't work like you think. Since `item` is statically typed as an `A*`, assigning the casted pointer back to `item` just ends up giving you the same pointer that you started with. You need something more like this instead: `if(type == NUMBER) { B *b = static_cast<B*>(item); b->get(); } else if(type == STRING) { C *c = static_cast<C*>(item); c->get(); }` and so on.

Comment: So `B::get()` is meant to return `void`?

Comment: @Timo. Thanks for mentioning that. I did some reseach and learned a lot although it may not work for my case.

Comment: @curiousguy. hmmm..... Good question. I think my original post was wrong. It is supposed to return int for B::get() and string for C::get(), which means the item->get() could return different type.

Comment: @JieLiu "_supposed to return int for (...)_" That changes a lot of things. It isn't possible to declare one pure virtual function with overriders in `B` and `C` then. We still don't know enough about the real problem being solved.

Comment: @JieLiu Are those types somewhat restricted, what do they have in common? Also which c++ version do you use? If the variation is too big, Remy Lebeau's answer might be the more simple and straight forward solution. Using some macros and a static registry probably reduces future overhead even more.

Comment: @Timo and curiousguy, Thanks for your comments. I admit that my original post was bad. I stuck yesterday. I have edited my question and hopefully it's more clear this time.

Comment: @Timo "_there is always the possibility of using type erasure_" how that different from "create a common interface type"?

Comment: @curiousguy In terms of logic, there isn't. However, if he is not able to create a base type (i.e. the source code of a type is not accessible, like in 3rd party code), type erasure is a good alternative as it doesn't rely on a common type hierarchy. If however, those types have nothing in common (i.e. identical function signatures) type erasure won't be that helpful aswell.

Comment: @Timo, yes, in my case. SeriesData, AT, IT and ST are in 3rd party code. However the return type will be different for some of the functions due to the different type of template argument. Does that mean it is not possible to just use the pointer of A to call functions.

Comment: @JieLiu In theory you could also make an additional erased type that accepts all possible return types. But this would only move your boilerplate code to another place instead of eliminating it. I cannot come up with a better solution than Remy Lebeau.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `type`-dependent operations in helper functions that are stored in lookup tables keyed by `type`, for example:

```
std::map<int, A*(*)()> makeAMap;
makeAMap[NUMBER] = []() -> A* { return new B; };
makeAMap[STRING] = []() -> A* { return new C; };
...

std::map<int, void(*)(A*)> getFuncMap;
getFuncMap[NUMBER] = [](A *item){ static_cast<B*>(item)->get(); };
getFuncMap[STRING] = [](A *item){ static_cast<C*>(item)->get(); };
...

A* item = makeAMap[type]();
...
item->common();    
getFuncMap[type](item);
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/EHsfQV)